# Dynamically Changing Simple Form Select on Another Select Change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a requirement to modify a select box based on changes made in a previous selection.

In this case I have a simple_form form with a country selection. If a user selects a particular country, a second select field will contain business entity types for the selected country.

For example, in Australia you'd have Sole Trader, Pty Ltd, etc. In the US, you have LLC, S Corp, C Corp, etc.

What I need is to be able to dynamically change the second selection box when the user chooses or changes the selected country.

I'd appreciate your suggestions on how to proceed. I'm using Rails 4 with jquery. Is JavaScript the best/only way to go here, or are their other options for doing this with Rails? Cheers.

Comment: If you're doing this on the client side (which I think is true) then there's no other way but JavaScript/jQuery. Also add js/jquery to the question tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript/Jquery is the best way to do this. Bind a change event to your country select list and based on selected country, change the option tags of business entity

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. This does help. But can you explain what you mean by changing the option tags.

Comment: For every select, options come from     <option values='foo'>foo-bar</options> tags. So change the options tags will change the content of select list. Try inspecting any page having select list and check the option tags. You will understand what I am trying to say. :)

Comment: Could this answer provide a bit more detail? Thanks!